# What is difference of LLVMInt32Type and LLVMInt32TypeInContext in LLVM C API?

Tags: llvm

LLVM C API provides `LLVMInt32Type` and `LLVMInt32TypeInContext` for the 32 bit integer type.
Which should we use, and why?